# How remove options before post request? React

Tags: reactjs

How to remove options before post?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please describe more about your error?

Comment: @Ahmad Ajaj it's not sufficient to answer your question please explain more.

Comment: How is this question related to `reactjs`?